# get_post_meta does not accept variable for some reason

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a meta value set for a post. The meta is '_test_field_one' and the value is "Cats".
I've made the following function just to test it (it's in a class, yes):

```
public function get( $post_id, $metakey ) {

    echo $metakey; // test_field_one

    $metakey = '_' . $metakey;    
    echo $metakey; // _test_field_one

    echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $metakey, true ); // nothing ..
    echo get_post_meta( $post_id, '_test_field_one', true ); // Cats

    return get_post_meta( $post_id, $metakey, true );
}
```

In the comments after each echo I've indicated what gets printed on the screen.
Does anyone know what is the reason for the third echo to not work (additionally the function returns nothing).

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump('_test_field_one' === $metakey)`?

Comment: Then there probably are some spaces at the end of `$metakey`. Try to pass it as `trim($metakey)`.

Comment: Really, now ? :D Thank you, good sir, this was the issue, indeed. You can post it as an answer if you wish, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparantly `$metakey` and `'_test_field_one'` are unequal but appear equal when echoed. The most likely solution is that `$metakey` has some trailing spaces. You can remove them using `trim($metakey)`.

[Official documentation](http://www.php.net/trim)